# Issue with Modal dialogue in mvc4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

In my mvc site, I am using a modal dialogue for contact us form. Everything works fine except the menu. The menu will be in the foreground. I want the menu to be blurred out like the other page elements. How can I achieve this?

Following is the css file I am using for the menu

```
.preload1 {background: url(../Images/three_0a.gif);}
.preload2 {background: url(../Images/three_1a.gif);}

#nav {padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none; height:38px; background:#fff url(../Images/three_0.gif) repeat-x; position:relative; z-index:500; font-family:arial, verdana, sans-serif;}
#nav li.top {display:block; float:left;}
#nav li a.top_link {display:block; float:left; height:35px; line-height:33px; color:#ccc; text-decoration:none; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; padding:0 0 0 12px; cursor:pointer;background: url(../Images/three_0.gif);}
#nav li a.top_link span {float:left; display:block; padding:0 24px 0 12px; height:35px; background: url(../Images/three_0.gif) right top no-repeat;}
#nav li a.top_link span.down {float:left; display:block; padding:0 24px 0 12px; height:35px; background: url(../Images/three_0a.gif) no-repeat right top;}

#nav li:hover a.top_link {color:#fff; background: url(../Images/three_1.gif) no-repeat;}
#nav li:hover a.top_link span {background:url(../Images/three_1.gif) no-repeat right top;}
#nav li:hover a.top_link span.down {background:url(../Images/three_1a.gif) no-repeat right top; padding-bottom:3px;}

/* Default list styling */

#nav li:hover {position:relative; z-index:200;}

#nav li:hover ul.sub
{left:1px; top:38px; background: #50b5d0; padding:3px; border:1px solid #0b4d97; white-space:nowrap; width:90px; height:auto; z-index:300;}
#nav li:hover ul.sub li
{display:block; height:20px; position:relative; float:left; width:90px; font-weight:normal;}
#nav li:hover ul.sub li a
{display:block; font-size:11px; height:18px; width:88px; line-height:18px; text-indent:5px; color:#000; text-decoration:none;border:1px solid #50b5d0;}
#nav li ul.sub li a.fly
{background:#50b5d0 url(../Images/arrow.gif) 80px 6px no-repeat;}
#nav li:hover ul.sub li a:hover 
{background:#3f96a9; color:#fff; border-color:#fff;}
#nav li:hover ul.sub li a.fly:hover
{background:#3f96a9 url(../Images/arrow_over.gif) 80px 6px no-repeat; color:#fff;}

#nav li b {display:block; font-size:11px; height:18px; width:88px; line-height:18px; margin-bottom:3px; text-indent:6px; color:#ff6; border-bottom:1px solid #ff6; cursor:default;}

#nav li:hover li:hover ul,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover ul,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover ul,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover ul
{left:90px; top:-4px; background: #50b5d0; padding:3px; border:1px solid #0b4d97; white-space:nowrap; width:90px; z-index:400; height:auto;}

#nav ul, 
#nav li:hover ul ul,
#nav li:hover li:hover ul ul,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover ul ul,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover ul ul
{position:absolute; left:-9999px; top:-9999px; width:0; height:0; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}

#nav li:hover li:hover a.fly,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover a.fly,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a.fly,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a.fly
{background:#3f96a9 url(../Images/arrow_over.gif) 80px 6px no-repeat; color:#fff; border-color:#fff;} 

#nav li:hover li:hover li a.fly,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li a.fly,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li a.fly
{background:#50b5d0 url(../Images/arrow.gif) 80px 6px no-repeat; color:#000; border-color:#50b5d0;}
```

Comment: You should put the code and we don't see your menu? And it looks like a CSS problem

Comment: Its a css problem. you should paste your code first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z-index property in the css was causing the issue. Fixed the issue by reducing the z-index value to 1 from 500.